Captions not generating in Python MoviePy script
I am working on a Python script using the MoviePy library to add captions to a video. However, I am encountering an issue where the captions are not being generated as expected.
Here's what I'm trying to do in the addCaptions method:

Load the video file.

Extract the audio from the video.

Transcribe the audio using the Google Speech Recognition API.

Overlay the transcription as captions on the video.

Write the video with captions to a new file.
However, I'm facing two specific issues:

Recognition request failed: I'm getting a "Bad Request" error when trying to transcribe the audio using the Google Speech Recognition API.

MoviePy Error: After attempting to add the captions, I encounter a "creation of None failed" error related to MoviePy.
def addCaptions(self):
    video = VideoFileClip(OUTPUT_FOLDER + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME + ".mp4")
    audio = video.audio
    temp_audio_path = OUTPUT_FOLDER + "temp_audio/temp_audio.wav"
    audio.write_audiofile(temp_audio_path, fps=audio.fps, codec='pcm_s16le')
    video.close()
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    transcription = ""
    with sr.AudioFile(temp_audio_path) as source:
        audio_data = r.record(source)
    try:
        transcription = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Unable to transcribe audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Recognition request failed:", e.reason)

    os.remove(temp_audio_path)

    font = "Arial"  
    fontsize = 24  
    txt_clip = TextClip(transcription, fontsize=fontsize, font=font, color='white')
    caption_video = CompositeVideoClip([video, txt_clip.set_pos(('center', 0.9))]) 
    caption_video.write_videofile(OUTPUT_FOLDER + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME + "_with_captions.mp4")
    video.close()






I expected the script to generate a video file with captions overlaid on the original video.
The code is generating audio and video file of the outputs but its just not generating the captions.
It is giveing me this error
Recognition request failed: Bad Request
MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

First of all, I'd recommend using a platform called AssemblyAI, their transcription is very accurate and the free tier is insanely generous.
If you'd still like to go with the GSR API, then try writing the results into an SRT-file first, before providing them as a parameter to the TextClip class.
Here is an example:
txt_clip = TextClip(filename="my_subtitles.srt", fontsize=60, font="Arial", color="#FFFF00")

Further debugging:

Try building the paths using the OS modules' os.path.join() function
Remove the codec parameter in the write_audiofile function

